# r twitter userTimeline error oauth

Tags: r, twitter

I am trying to retrieve tweets of a number of users in R using the twitteR library. setup_twitter_oauth and a number of other functions like getUser, getFollowers all work fine. My problem is when I try to use userTimeline within lapply (or a for loop), it gave me an OAuth authentication errors. (Running userTimeline on its own works properly.) I used getCurRateLimitInfo() after the error returned, and all the commands show available limits.

Here is the snippet of code I ran.

```
...
library("twitteR")
setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)
my_user <- getUser("my_twitter_name")
my_followers <- my_user$getFollowers(n=100)
tweets <- unlist(lapply(my_followers, function(x) userTimeline(x$id, n=100)))
```

Error from running lapply (with traceback):

```
Error in twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) :

OAuth authentication error:
This most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()' 
10 stop("OAuth authentication error:\nThis most likely means that you have incorrectly called setup_twitter_oauth()'") 
9 twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(cmd, params, method, ...) 
8 doPagedAPICall(cmd, n, params, ...) 
7 lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) 
6 sapply(doPagedAPICall(cmd, n, params, ...), buildStatus) 
5 statusBase(cmd, params, n, 3200, ...) 
4 userTimeline(x$id, n = 100) 
3 FUN(X[[i]], ...) 
2 lapply(my_followers, function(x) userTimeline(x$id, n = 100)) 
1 unlist(lapply(my_followers, function(x) userTimeline(x$id, n = 100)))
```

I did look up OAuth errors and it seems to mostly occur during setup_twitter_oauth, but not other functions. A couple of questions:

- What caused this error and how to resolve it?
- My end goal is to get a vector of tweets from followers or a data frame holding the follower user name and tweets.  Is there a more efficient way to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Removing protected users solved it.
Try something like `my_followers <- my_followers[protected == FALSE]` and it should work.